# MongoDB In-Memory Storage engine : what happens when memory is full?

Tags: mongodb, in-memory

I did not find answer in the mongodb documentation. What happens when the memory is full when using the MongoDB In-Memory Storage Engine?

Is there an eviction (LRU)?
Is there an error message ?
Is it configurable ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the in-memory storage engine uses 50% of physical RAM minus 1 GB.

If a write operation would cause the data to exceed the specified memory size, MongoDB returns with the error:

> "WT_CACHE_FULL: operation would overflow cache"

To specify a new size, use the storage.inMemory.engineConfig.inMemorySizeGB
 setting in the YAML configuration file format:

```
storage:
   engine: inMemory
   dbPath: <path>
   inMemory:
      engineConfig:
         inMemorySizeGB: <newSize>
```

Or use the command-line option --inMemorySizeGB:

```
mongod --storageEngine inMemory --dbpath <path> --inMemorySizeGB <newSize>
```

Btw, I found this in the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/#memory-use), you may want to explore more.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that if I need an eviction I can use a capped collection with the In-memory storage engine.